# Actor input not firing any input event

Tags: android, libgdx

I have read some of the answers here at stackoverflow trying to figure out why my SpriteActor input events are not being fire without any luck. Don't know what I'm doing wrong. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

-Screen class

```
public class MainGameScreen implements Screen
{

Stage _stage;

public MainGameScreen()
{
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    _stage=new Stage(w,h,true);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(_stage);

    TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/texturesHD.atlas"));

    SpriteActor actor= new SpriteActor(atlas,"BtTemple",true);
    actor.x=w/2.0f;
    actor.y=h/2.0f;


    _stage.addActor(actor);
}

public void     dispose()
{
}

public void     hide()
{
}


public void     resize(int width, int height)
{
}

public void     resume()
{
}

public void     show()
{
}

public void render(float deltaTime) 
{
    _stage.draw();
}   
public void pauseGame() 
{
}

// this is called by android 
public void pause() 
{
}
```

}

And here my SpriteActor class:

```
class SpriteActor extends Actor 
{
private Sprite _sprite;


public SpriteActor(TextureAtlas atlas, String regionName, boolean touchable) 
{   
    super();

    _sprite = atlas.createSprite(regionName);

    //setWidth(_sprite.getWidth());
    //setHeight(_sprite.getHeight());
    //setBounds(x,y,getWidth(),getHeight());

    this.touchable=touchable;
}

@Override
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) 
{
    /*Color color = getColor();
    batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);*/
    batch.draw(_sprite, x, y);
}

@Override
public Actor hit(float x, float y)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown (float x, float y, int pointer) 
{
    Gdx.app.debug("Game", "TestActor.touchDown()");
    return true;  // must return true for touchUp event to occur
}
@Override
public void touchUp (float x, float y, int pointer) 
{
    Gdx.app.debug("Game", "TestActor.touchUp()");
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
public class MainGameScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor {
```

Move the setInputProcessor to the show() method like this:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}
```

And implement methods from the InputProcessor:

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    //do whatever you want
    return _stage.keyDown(keycode);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have done what you did and I'm now receiving input on My Screen class, but my sprite is not receiving input yet :/. On the other hand I can understand what you did, but won't it be the same just setting the scene as the input processor? You are really doing this. Just you get input on Screen and delegates then to the stage. By the way, thanks a lot giving a hand here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I will answer my own question. The problem was that I had provided a hit method that was returning null, so when checking by the system this was never hit.